# Какое слово вставить на место пропуска?

Tags: егэ

Дан текст:

> (1)Со­глас­но на­блю­де­ни­ям со­вре­мен­ных ис­сле­до­ва­те­лей у че­ло­ве­ка, по­лу­ча­ю­ще­го ос­нов­ную ин­фор­ма­цию в Сети, ме­ня­ет­ся «при­ро­да» чте­ния. (2)Раз­ви­ва­ют­ся на­вы­ки по­верх­ност­но­го, ска­ни­ру­ю­ще­го чте­ния, а остав­ший­ся без упо­треб­ле­ния навык вни­ма­тель­но­го чте­ния длин­но­го тек­ста ис­че­за­ет, как любая спо­соб­ность, ко­то­рую не тре­ни­ру­ют. (3)<...> со­зна­ние, при­вык­шее ра­бо­тать с мел­ки­ми ку­соч­ка­ми и от­дель­ны­ми фраг­мен­та­ми, не свя­зан­ны­ми между собой, плохо справ­ля­ет­ся с боль­ши­ми тек­ста­ми, тре­бу­ю­щи­ми вре­ме­ни и вни­ма­ния.

Какое из при­ведённых ниже слов (со­че­та­ний слов) долж­но быть на месте про­пус­ка в тре­тьем пред­ло­же­нии?

- Од­на­ко
- Вслед­ствие этого
- Даже
- Не­смот­ря на это,
- Сле­до­ва­тель­но,

Ответ - "вследствие этого". Почему не "следовательно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Вследствие этого" - поясняет, что ранее сказанное (это может быть и не одно суждение) является причиной того, о чём говорится далее.

"Следовательно" - констатирует, что неизбежным и очевидным для адресата выводом из ранее сказанного (обычно одно суждение) является то, о чем говорится сразу за этим.

В данном случае из (1) и (2) читателю самому не сделать однозначного вывода в пользу (3), поэтому "следовательно" отпадает.